# React Nested array not working, Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-functional-component, nested-map

I am using react functional component. When I run react it outputs this error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"`

Sample Data

```
const tabData = [{
    key: 0,
    label: 'Theory',
    color: 'primary',
    theory: [{
        key: 0,
        title: 'Analyze one dimensional and two dime',
        content: [
                'Kinematics',
                'Rectilinear motion under constant acceleration',
                'Equations of motion',
        ],
    }]
}];
```

My function

```
{tabData.map((data) => {
    return (
        <TabPanel value={value} index={data.key}>
           <ul index={data.key}>
              {data.theory.map((tit) => {
                 return (<li key={tit.key}>{tit.title}</li>);
              })}
          </ul>
        </TabPanel>
    );
```

})}

Answer (score 1):

Use optional chaining for this case. It's much shorter and cleaner.

```
{tabData?.map((data) => {
    return (
      <TabPanel value={value} index={data.key}>
        <ul index={data.key}>
        {data.theory.map((tit) => {
          return (<li key={tit.key}>{tit.title}</li>);
        })}
        </ul>
     </TabPanel>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this

```
{tabData && tabData.length > 0 && tabData.map((data) => {
    return (
      <TabPanel value={value} index={data.key}>
        <ul index={data.key}>
        {data && data.theory && data.theory.length > 0 && data.theory.map((tit) => {
          return (<li key={tit.key}>{tit.title}</li>);
        })}
        </ul>
     </TabPanel>
    );
})}
```